# The element 'Capabilities' in namespace msix Package.appmanifest xml

Tags: msix

I have a warning highlighted for the element:

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="localSystemServices" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packagedServices" />
</Capabilities>
```

With the below detail:

```
The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid
child element 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'. List of possible elements
expected: 'CapabilityChoice' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as
'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in
namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4' as well as 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6' as well as 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/7' as well as 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3' as well as 'Capability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/2' as well as 'CustomCapabilityChoice' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' as well as 'CustomCapability' in namespace
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/4' as well as 'Dev....
```

The Package.appmanifest xml manifest is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  xmlns:desktop2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/2"
  xmlns:desktop6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/6"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap">

  <Identity
    Name="11d14331-0000-0000-0000-3c2e4cc6d69d"
    Publisher="CN=my.name"
    Version="1.0.10.0" />

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>My Agent</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>My</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Images\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="My Agent"
        Description="My Agent."
        BackgroundColor="transparent"
        Square150x150Logo="Images\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Images\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Images\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Images\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <desktop6:Extension Category="windows.service" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Executable="Agent\Agent.exe">
          <desktop6:Service Name="Agent" StartAccount="localSystem" StartupType="auto"/>
        </desktop6:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="localSystemServices" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packagedServices" />
  </Capabilities>

  <Extensions>
      <desktop2:Extension Category="windows.firewallRules">
          <desktop2:FirewallRules Executable="Agent\Agent.exe">
              <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="TCP" Profile="all"/>
              <desktop2:Rule Direction="in" IPProtocol="UDP"
                             Profile="all"/>
              <desktop2:Rule Direction="out"
                             IPProtocol="TCP"
                             Profile="all"/>
              <desktop2:Rule Direction="out"
                             IPProtocol="UDP"
                             Profile="all"/>
          </desktop2:FirewallRules>
      </desktop2:Extension>
  </Extensions>
</Package>
```